# the usage of 'as' : as they consider different things they can pretend to do

Tags: meaning-in-context, conjunctions

> Pretending to be someone else, with all the gestures, actions, and language that involves, gives children practice thinking divergently **as** they consider different things they can pretend to do.

What's the exact meaning of 'as' here? Does this mean 'because'?

Comment: Either *because*, or *during the time that*.  Both readings seem plausible, particularly because this part of the sentence seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it means "because". "as" here is a conjunction:

> because; since [Source](https://www.lexico.com/definition/as)

Comment: I disagree.  Pretending to be someone else gives children practice thinking divergently *because* they consider different things they can pretend to do?   That sounds redundant, essentially being "Pretending gives them practice because they're thinking about pretending."  I think **while** is a more sensible meaning of *as* here.

Answer (score 0):

I think "in that" would be a good paraphrase. The subordinate clause spells out in what way pretend play is good practice for thinking divergently.